# ViewStub's layout root element margins

Tags: android

LinearLayout doesn't have margins after iflating ViewStub. After inflating I can set margins only programmaticaly or there is another way?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue but with a RelativeLayout. I fixed it by putting the margins on the ViewStub definition. This may not be the best way to do it, the best way might be having a hierarchical layout where the first child of your root layout is the one that has the margins set and contains all other elements.

Not sure of the root cause for this, but these are the two workarounds I know of.

Answer (score 5):

Method 1:
      As per Android developer website,Whenever you use ViewStub,its layout parameters are passed to inflated child.So to set layout parameters such as marginLeft,marginTop,marginRight,marginBottom,you have to set the values to ViewStub,which will be passed to inflated child.

[image]

Method 2:Or else after the ViewStub is made visible,you can dynamically create LayoutParams and set to the ViewGroup.This also works.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.leftMargin =getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.four);
        params.rightMargin=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.four);
        params.bottomMargin=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.eight);
        findViewById(R.id.linearLayout).setLayoutParams(params);
```